# Looping Variables in a session

Tags: loops, session, coldfusion, session-variables

I am trying to loop variables through a session. On the previous page I have a dropdown that lets the user select 1 thru 5 which is set as variable pcount. Depending on what the user chooses the form on the next page duplicates that many times(pcount). I need to be able to loop the variables through the session so it knows "firstname_1" "firstname_2" etc... and then displav on my last screen as session #session.checkout.info.firstname_#Peoplecount#. I can not figure out how to properly write variables in the session. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <cfset Peoplecount = 1>
    <cfloop
     index="Add"
     from="1"
     to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#"
     step="1"
    >
        <!---
        If no checkout, send them to step 1
        --->

        <cfif not structKeyExists(session, "checkout")>
            <cflocation url="enter.cfm" addToken="false">
        </cfif>
        <!--- initial defaults for the section --->
        <cfif not structKeyExists(session.checkout, "info")>
            <cfset session.checkout.info = {firstname_#Peoplecount#=""}>
        </cfif>

        <!--- form fields will default according to session values---> 
        <cfparam name="form.firstname_#Peoplecount#" 
default="#session.checkout.info.firstname_#Peoplecount#">


        <cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>

            <cfset errors = []>
        <cfif not arrayLen(errors)>
                <cfset session.checkout.info =
     {firstname_#Peoplecount#=form.firstname_#Peoplecount#}>
               <cfset Peoplecount = PeopleCount + 1>


             </cfloop>
                <cflocation url="ownerCheck.cfm" addToken="false">
            </cfif>

    </cfif>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I can think of two things that might help you.  First, only do in a loop what is necessary to do in a loop.  In your case, checking for session.checkout should be done before the loop.  Second, for setting variables with dynamic names, array notation is your freind.  <cfset x["staticPart" & dynamicPart] = "something">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<cfset session.checkout.info =
     {firstname_#Peoplecount#=form.firstname_#Peoplecount#}>
```

Should be more like:

```
<cfset session.checkout.info = {
    "firstname_#Peoplecount#" = form["firstname_#Peoplecount#"]
}>
```

**Update:**

Create `session.checkout.info` as an empty struct first, before you start your loop:

```
<cfset session.checkout.info = {}>
```

Then inside your IF statement, add the key and value you want, e.g.

```
<cfset session.checkout.info["firstname_#Peoplecount#"] = form["firstname_#Peoplecount#"]>
```

Comment: IF that is the exact error you are getting, you did not implement was was suggested.

Comment: you go `<cfloop> ... <cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")> ... </cfloop> ... </cfif></cfif>`  The `</cfloop>` should be the last one there, and it looks like one-too-many `</cfif>` closing tags

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Put a cfdump inside your loop so you can see what is happening to you.

Comment: @DB7 you're always overwriting the value of `session.checkout.info`.  Instead create it once as an empty struct before your loop starts. Then append the `"firstname_#Peoplecount#" = form["firstname_#Peoplecount#"]` key-value into it.  I'll update my answer with an example